# Intriguing everyday question but can it have a mathematical answer?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a group of five teams playing on a soccer competition. As you know the victory is rewarded with three points, a draw with one point and a defeat with zero points. The matches are in the two legged format, home and away match. Can we have a possible combinatorics answer to the amount of points needed to secure a third place, I don't care about the rigourousness of the proof, hey it's soccer anything can happen but I was really eager to ask someone who likes these seemingly math related problems. In advance thanks to everyone who takes the time to read all this.

Comment: Each pair of teams plays each other twice?

Comment: yes, its like having A B teams and they play A vs B and B vs A and thank you for your interest

Comment: When you say "needed to secure a third place", do you mean $x$ points such that a team that finishes with $x$ points will **always** get at least third place, or that it is **possible** for a team to finish with $x$ points and get third place?  And does "third place" include a tie for third place?

Comment: I mean to try mathematically to give an answer of an least upper bound for a team to be in the third place and I think that the right question is your first one

Comment: Are you there @RobertIsrael

Answer (score 1):

If my program is correct, with $14$ or $15$ points a team is guaranteed at least a tie for third place.  For example, if the results were as follows (the entry in row i, column j are the points earned by team i in its matches with team j), four teams would be tied with $14$ points.
$$ \pmatrix{ - & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
             6 & - & 6 & 2 & 0\cr
             6 & 0  & - & 6 & 2\cr
             6 & 2  & 0 & - & 6\cr
             6 & 6 & 2 & 0 & -\cr}$$

Change the $2$'s to $3$'s (i.e. a win and a loss instead of two draws) to get
a case where four teams are tied with $15$ points.

With $13$ points it is possible to finish in fourth place.  For example,
this would happen in the above result if you changed one of the draws for team 2 to a loss.

With $16$ points a team is guaranteed at least a clear third place.

Comment: thank you very much @Robert Israel, you have been really helpful